# issue while migration[wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

i wanted to implement an attachement field of video, images. and files(pdf.doc)  field vis PAPERCLIP but after creating a migration "rails g paperclip projects image"  and rails db:migrate  it gives error

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 19493
== 20230116080101 AddAttachmentAvatarToProjects: migrating ====================
-- change_table(:projects)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:603:in `column'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in attachment'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `each_pair'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `block in attachment'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `attachment'
/var/www/html/rails/workshop_project3/db/migrate/20230116080101_add_attachment_avatar_to_projects.rb:4:in `block in up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:108:in `block in change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:43:in `block in change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:490:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:929:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:43:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:108:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:658:in `method_missing'
/var/www/html/rails/workshop_project3/db/migrate/20230116080101_add_attachment_avatar_to_projects.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:870:in `public_send'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:870:in `exec_migration'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1329:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1328:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `migrate_without_lock'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1253:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
<internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:603:in `column'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in attachment'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `each_pair'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `block in attachment'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/paperclip-6.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `attachment'
/var/www/html/rails/workshop_project3/db/migrate/20230116080101_add_attachment_avatar_to_projects.rb:4:in `block in up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:108:in `block in change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:43:in `block in change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:490:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:929:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:43:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:108:in `change_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:658:in `method_missing'
/var/www/html/rails/workshop_project3/db/migrate/20230116080101_add_attachment_avatar_to_projects.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:870:in `public_send'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:870:in `exec_migration'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1329:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1328:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `migrate_without_lock'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1253:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
<internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

expecting for execution of migration on rails6

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First of all, Paperclip is deprecated now. But, by looking at the docs, you might need to pass a model name, not table name. Try: `rails g paperclip project image`

Answer (score 0):

[Paperclip was deprecated](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/closing-the-trombone) in 2018 in favor of ActiveStorage (introduced in Rails 5.2), and in fact in Rails 6 and beyond [it doesn't even generate a valid migration](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/c769382c9b7078f3d1620b50ec2a70e91ba62ec4/lib/generators/paperclip/paperclip_generator.rb#L33-L37).

Use ActiveStorage. There's a migration guide in the README and the blog post.